# Fridge water spout stops working due to ice formation

Tags: refrigerator

We have a GE Cafe refrigerator with a water/ice dispenser that stops working regularly. I identified the issue to ice formation around the water spout which prevents the actuator housing from moving back far enough to trigger the actuator circuit. It’s fairly easy to disconnect the panel, remove the dispenser housing, melt the ice and put it all back together. Doing this every 3-4 weeks is fairly annoying.

I am unable to see where the water leak is coming from to form the ice. It’s just under the ice dispenser spout and the ice forms at the base of the water spout.
[image]
Any thoughts on how to fix this ?

Thanks
V

Comment: A couple weeks ago, I replaced the Ice flapper and the solenoid that controls it. All worked well for a couple days and then the water dispensing stopped. Ice still works perfectly. I have since squirted hot salt water up the water dispenser tube to unfreeze the ice. Apparently the insulation around the water tube close to the dispenser ages in about 15 years. I have added some insulation (stuck a pot holder on) on the inside door panel to see if that prevents water from freezing. Next step is to install the water tube heater GE WR49X10173 and see if that works as advertised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The insulation was all that was needed to prevent the water pipe from freezing. It’s been 10 weeks and the water dispenser is still working well.

[image]